# Javascript variable problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a variable in javascript:

```
var activeSearchButton = document.getElementById('<%=btnSearch.ClientID %>');
```

I want to set it like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="WFTo" runat="server" onchange="activeSearchButton = document.getElementById('<%=btnWFSearch.ClientID %>');"></asp:TextBox>
```

When I am trying to use the varible in javascript function, it is null. And the source shows:

```
onchange="activeSearchButton = document.getElementById('&lt;%=btnSearch.ClientID %>');"
```

I noticed '& lt;' instead of "<". Is this the reason of my problem? Why does this happen? Or maybe there is another reason?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Server side controls are replaced by the server, that is what asp.net is all about :D that is the reason you cannot find that control.

Comment: So why doesn't it replace it for me? I expected onchange="activeSearchButton = document.getElementById('ctl00_CPHDefault_tcTPS_TPProd_ctl01_tcProduction_TPTitleProgress_btnSearch'');"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a function in `<script />` section

```
function setActiveSearchButton()
{
    activeSearchButton = document.getElementById('<%=btnSearch.ClientID %>');
}
```

and use

```
<asp:TextBox ID="WFTo" runat="server" onchange="setActiveSearchButton()"></asp:TextBox>
```

EDIT:

As it turns out, you cannot use `<%= .. %>` for server side controls. You'll have to resolve to using a regular html input like this

```
<input type="text" onchange="setActiveSearchButton('<%= btnSearch.ClientID %>')" />
```

and

```
function setActiveSearchButton(buttonId)
{
    activeSearchButton = document.getElementById(buttonId);
}
```

or leave the `<asp:TextBox />` as it is and on Page_Load do

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     WFTo.Attributes.Add("onchange", "setActiveSearchButton('" + btnSearch.ClientID +"')");
 }
```

Comment: I could create such a function, but I have more than one button, and I would prefer not to create a function for each of them. Can I pass the button's ClientID into the function? I tried this: onchange="setActiveSearchButton(document.getElementById('<%=btnSearch.ClientID %>'));", but it gives me the same problem as before. Is what I want impossible? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to set activeSearchButton to btnSearch, not to the textbox whose change fires the event.

Comment: I made setActiveSearchButton(button) exactly like you did. But the problem is how to pass the button's id. As I have already said, "btnSearch" is not replaced with the ClientID.

Comment: I don't see any changes. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Still doesn't work: onchange="setActiveSearchButton('&lt;%=btnSearch.ClientID %>')

Comment: @dpreznik which one did you try? changing it to `<input type="text"..` or adding attribute from codebehind?

Comment: Adding attribute from code-behind: WFFrom.Attributes.Add("onchange", "setActiveSearchButton('" + btnWFSearch.ClientID + "')"); WFTo.Attributes.Add("onchange", "setActiveSearchButton('" + btnWFSearch.ClientID + "')"); txtFilterValue.Attributes.Add("onchange", "setActiveSearchButton('" + btnSearch.ClientID + "')"); filterFrom.Attributes.Add("onchange", "setActiveSearchButton('" + btnSearch.ClientID + "')"); filterTo.Attributes.Add("onchange", "setActiveSearchButton('" + btnSearch.ClientID + "')"); I cannot use an html textbox, I need to handle the click in code-behind.

Comment: @dpreznik no clue. I tried a simple example and it seems to work fine for me. If you want I link my example code for you, if it would help.

Comment: Never mind. I just made a function for each button, as you suggested in the beginning, and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
onchange='<% = string.Format("activeSearchButton = document.getElementById(\"{0}\");", btnWFSearch.ClientID) %>'
```

EDIT: As our friend said, we can only do this in a "input" control. For a TextBox the best way is add a parameter in codebehind.